# ListBoxItem and Hyperlinks

Tags: c#, wpf, hyperlink, listboxitem

I've got a few ListBoxItems that have an image and a textbox in them which highlights when clicked. What I'm having trouble figuring out is how to make whole listbox item doubleclick event fire to a hyperlink. Can someone assist me in this?

I've been looking at this but it seems that it is for the listbox as a whole rather than an item -- http://jarloo.com/code/wpf/wpf-listbox-doubleclick/.

Here is one of my listboxitems:

```
 <ListBoxItem >
     <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid Margin="5">
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <Border  Grid.RowSpan="2"
         BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="0"
         Margin="0,0,5,0">
     <Image Source="/IDE;component/Resources/Images/test1.ico" Height="64" Width="64" />
         </Border>
         <TextBlock Text="Google.com"
          FontWeight="Bold"
          Grid.Column="2"
          Margin="0,0,0,5"/>
     <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="To learn more information doubleclick this box to open the website."
         Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2"/>
     </Grid>
     <Line X1="0" Y1="0" X2="0" Y2="0" Stretch="Uniform"
         Stroke="DarkGray"
         VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
     </Grid>
 </ListBoxItem>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be specifying concrete items rather than having them generated from an ItemsSource, the link you named does not apply. I don't quite understand what you mean when you refer to a Hyperlink since i cannot see any in your code.

To handle a normal double click you could assign a handler in the ListBoxItem itself:

```
<ListBoxItem MouseDoubleClick="ListBoxItem_DoubleClick">
    ...
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: ahh! thanks for this. i kept trying <Hyperlink> but it wouldn't allow it. cheers